# Retransform data into original form?

Tags: r

I have a time series data which consist of 24 hours of the electricity demand. I transform the data into stationary from through differences, Now after forecasting for one year, I want to transform the data into its original form to check the accuracy of the model. I want to explain my question by an example

```
    dat <- c(5,24,23,12,14,15,16,17,18,22,24)
    sat<- diff(dat)
 sat
 [1]  19  -1 -11   2   1   1   1   1   4   2
 ori <- diffinv(sat)
> ori
 [1]  0 19 18  7  9 10 11 12 13 17 19
```

By using the **diffinv** which is the inverse of the difference, but the result I obtain is the original data **dat**. Know can any one help me that how I obtain the original data **dat**, mean the result of **dat** and **ori** are different.

Comment: Add the initial data value, 5, to `ori`.

Comment: thanks whuber but adding the frist value does not reproduce my original data given as **dat**

Comment: That baffles me, because when I add 5 to each value of `ori` as shown in your post I recover the vector `dat` as shown in your post.  Please clarify what your problem is. In a comment to the answer you mistakenly compute `diffinv(dat)` rather than `diffinv(sat)`.

Comment: thanks alot its realy work in this example which i mentioned, but when i apply the same you suggest me it does not retransform exactly, i going a sample of my data           **a13<-c( 82.81334,75.76743,59.91985,59.92093,59.01000,58.50000,58.53782,61.10340,57.84142,62.26768,62.90752)** then** a14<- diff(a13)** so **a15<- 82.81344+diffinv(a14)** the result i obtained as ** 82.81344, 75.76753, 59.91995, 59.92103, 59.01010, 58.50010, 58.53792, 61.10350, 57.84152
 62.26778, 62.90762** which not the same as **a13**

Comment: Because the results are identical up to that point, clearly this is not a statistical question: you need to figure out what `diffinv` is really doing.  Its manual page may provide clues; otherwise you need to do some testing of your software.

Answer (score 1):

In `diff`ing you loose information about the first value, in your example $5$

This will work:

```
dat <- c(5,24,23,12,14,15,16,17,18,22,24)
sat<- diff(dat)
5 + diffinv(sat)
```

or in the general case

```
dat <- c(5,24,23,12,14,15,16,17,18,22,24)
print(dat[1] + diffinv(dat))
```

alternatively you can use the `xi` argument

```
print(diffinv(diff(dat), xi = 5))
```

You can also see `xi` being used in

```
example(diffinv)
```

Comment: Thanks Berhard for your reply, but this is not solution that i required i want that how to obtain the orgion data **dat**,but your suggestion give me the ans as dat <- **c(5,24,23,12,14,15,16,17,18,22,24)**
**print(dat[1] + diffinv(dat))**
 **[1]   5  10  34  57  69  83  98 114 131 149 171 195** so its is not that as **dat** plz suggest how to obtain the original data